# How to do C++ style(indexed) nested loops in python?

Tags: loops, for-loop, python

What is the equivalent of the following in python?

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    for (j=i+1; j<n; j++)
        //do stuff with A[i], A[j]
```

Or in some sense, the following. It should also remove the element from A at the completion of each round of the loop.

```
for a in A:
    for a' in A/{a}: #i.e. rest of the elements of A
        #do something with a,a'
    #remove a from A
```

Is there a pythonic way of doing this without using enumerate()?

Edits:

Sorry for the bad description.

1. In the first example, I mean to use i & j only as indices. Their values do not matter. Its just a rough c++ equivalent of the latter.
2. The outer loop is executed n times. The inner loop is executed (n-1), (n-2)...0 times for each iteration of the outer loop.

Maybe this might help (pseudocode):

```
function next_iteration(list):
    head = first element
    tail = remaining elements #list
    each element in tail interacts with head one by one
    next_iteration(tail)
```

PS: All code samples above are pseudocodes. I'm trying to express something that is still a bit vague in my mind.

Comment: Your two loops don't do the same thing. Pick one!

Comment: @katrielalex -- not explicitly, but conceptually they could both represent nested loops over the same sequence, where the inner loop starts immediately after the current element in the outer loop.

Comment: The second example begins the inner loop at the start and only skips element `a`.

Comment: It need not be the 'next' element in the inner loop. The inner loop works on the 'remaining elements'. The next iteration is also on the remaining elements. Please see next_iteration to get a better idea.

Comment: Both katrielalex and hochl are correct I guess. I just have to use itertools.combinations instead of itertools.permutations. Is it possible to mark both as correct?

Comment: No, (un)fortunately you have to choose one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your two questions are different, here is solution for your second problem:

```
for i in xrange(len(A)):
    for j in xrange(len(A)):
        if i != j:
            do_stuff(A[i], A[j])
```

or **using** `itertools` (I think using the included **batteries** is very pythonic!):

```
import itertools

for a, b in itertools.permutations(A, 2):
    do_stuff(a, b)
```

This applies do_stuff to all combinations of 2 different elements from A. I you want to store the result just use:

```
[do_stuff(a, b) for a, b in itertools.permutations(A, 2)]
```

Comment: Hi, almost there. :)
Can you make it work in such a way that (a,b) and (b,a) are the same? That is, order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4):

I intepret what you're asking as

> How can I iterate over all pairs of distinct elements of a container?

Answer:

```
>>> x = {1,2,3}
>>> import itertools
>>> for a, b in itertools.permutations(x, 2):
...     print a, b
... 
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 3
3 1
3 2
```

EDIT: If you don't want both `(a,b)` and `(b,a)`, just use `itertools.combinations` instead.

Comment: All pairs of distinct elements, without considering the order of elements in each pair. how does this change to accomodate that?

Comment: @Karthick use `.combinations` instead. See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range (i+1,n):
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0,n):
   for j in range(i+1,n):
   # do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Still can't leave comments.. but basically what the other two posts said - but get in the habit of using xrange instead of range.

```
for i in xrange(0,n):
   for j in xrange(i+1,n):
   # do stuff
```

Comment: `range()` returns generator in python 3.x

Comment: It does, but the op never specified version so I tend to assume < 3.x :]

Comment: With 2.x on the way out and 3.x on the way in it is better to get in the habit of using `range`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xrange` to generate values for i and j respectively as show below:

```
for i in xrange(0, n):
   for j in xrange(i + 1, n):
       # do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make the inner loop directly over a slice.  Not saying this is any better, but it is another approach.

```
for i in range(0,len(x)):
  a = x[i]
  for b in x[i+1:]:
    print a, b
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach this is - if **n** is an sequence that provides the iterable interface, then in Python you can simplify your code by iterating over the object directly:

```
for i in n:
   for some_var in n[n.index(i):]: # rest of items
     # do something
```

I hope I understood your loop correctly, because as others have stated - they don't do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one of your questions, as already mentioned in other answers:

```
for i in xrange(n):
    for j in xrange(i+1, n):
        # do stuff with A[i] and A[j]
```

For the second one:

```
for i, a in enumerate(A):
    for b in A[i+1:]:
        # do stuff with a and b
```

Answer (score 0):

Your psuedocode almost has it:

```
function next_iteration(list):
    head = first element
    tail = remaining elements #list
    each element in tail interacts with head one by one
    next_iteration(tail)
```

Python code:

```
def next_iteration(lst):
    head, tail = lst[0], lst[1:]
    for item in tail:
        print(head, item)
    if tail:
        next_iteration(tail)
```

Which, when tried with `next_iteration([1, 2, 3])`, prints:

```
1 2
1 3
2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first for-loop, **enumerate()** walks through the array and makes the index,value of each element available to the second for-loop. In the second loop, **range()** makes j = i+1 --> len(a) available. At this point you'd have exactly what you need which is `i` & `j` to do your operation.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> array_len = len(a)
>>> for i,v in enumerate(a):
...   for j in range(i+1, array_len):
...     print a[i], a[j]
...
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 3
2 4
3 4
>>>
```