# CHALLENGE: most pythonic way of a nested loop about one element excluding itself

Tags: python, loops

I want to have a nested loop with inner and outer loop iterate over the same list. Also in the inner loop I don't want to have the same element as in the outer loop. I also need the indices.

An example of the straight forward way

```py
for i, line in enumerate(list_sentence):
        for j, line2 in enumerate(list_sentence):
            if i != j:
                if line in line2:
                    doing_stuff()
```

As line in line2 tells you i and j arent symmetric as line in line2 isnt the same as line2 in line is. One possible solution might to make symmetric.

Can you write a more python solution? This question is driven mostly by curiosity. One way I thought is using the product of collections but it would make the code less readable.

Comment: It's not clear from your question why you want to iterate through the list like this, by that I mean what are you trying to accomplish by looping like this. However, I think the itertools library may have solutions to what you're trying to do.

Comment: What is the output for `list_sentence = [1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: I think you mean pass if `i == j`, not `i != j`.

Comment: I wanna have a comparision between one element and all other elements of a list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do C++ style(indexed) nested loops in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787741/how-to-do-c-styleindexed-nested-loops-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific question, the `itertools.permutations` is better than my suggestion bellow.

One generic way to "hide away" complex selection of items to be looped upon is to
move the `for`s and `if`s into a generator. That way, your main code, with the important "do_stuff()" part remains flat. A docstring in the generator itself can explain what is going on, if it is needed -

```
def check_lines(seq):
    for i, line1 in enumerate(seq):
        for j, line2 in enumerate(seq):
             if i == j:  # keep things flat
                 continue 
             if line1 not in line2:  
                 continue
             yield (line1, line2)
```

and on your main code:

```
for line1, line2 in my_permut(list_sentence):
    # do_stuff code can go directly here, in a "flat enough" place:
    ...
```

I've used this in a couple times where I had a class to represent a board-game like structure (chess or checkerboard), or an image, and used the `__iter__` method to yield at once the x, y coordinates and the cell contents, as a tuple.

Instead of:

```
for x in board.width():
   for y in board.height():
      content = board[x, y]
      ...
```

the code becomes:

```
for x, y, content in board:
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

If i understood your question right you can use `itertools.permutations`.
This works only if you use the same array twice.

```
import itertools
list_sentence = [1, 2, 3]

for line1, line2 in itertools.permutations(list_sentence, 2):
    print(line1, line2)
```

The result is:

```
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 3
3 1
3 2
```

You only have to replace `print(line1, line2)` by  `if line1 in line2: doing_stuff()`.

Comment: I think that `combinations` would return the upper triangle, `permutations` returns everything except the diagonal.

Comment: Great solution! Never thought to use "mathematical methods"